# Python logging in multiprocessing

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

How to output logs to the console of several processes?
Example:

```
import multiprocessing, logging, multiprocessing_logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()
multiprocessing_logging.install_mp_handler(logger)

def worker():
    while True:
        logger.info("This is logging for TEST1")

def worker2():
    while True:
        logger.info("This is logging for TEST2")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
    p1.daemon = True
    p1.start()

    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker2)
    p2.daemon = True
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

But output is incorrect:

```
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST1
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST2
IINFO:root:This is logging for TEST1
NFO:root:This is logging for TEST2
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST1
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST2
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST1
IINFO:root:This is logging for TEST2
NFO:root:This is logging for TEST1
IINFO:root:This is logging for TEST2
NFO:root:This is logging for TEST1
```

I tried to use [multiprocessing-logging](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multiprocessing-logging/) library, but it doesn't helped

Comment: `multiprocessing-logging` looks like it should solve your problem -- can you provide a [MCVE] that shows what doesn't work when you're using it?

Comment: I just import multiprocessing-logging and add multiprocessing_logging.install_mp_handler() after configure the logging like it is written [link](https://github.com/jruere/multiprocessing-logging#usage)

Comment: In that case you should [file a bug report](https://github.com/jruere/multiprocessing-logging/issues/new) with `multiprocessing-logging`.

Comment: I don't think it is bug, because when creating new process, new logger object too creating, but logger object must be one for all processes. I think I misused with it

Comment: Then show us your code where you use `multiprocessing-logging` so we can help you to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your (updated) code works fine over here:

```
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST1
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST1
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST1
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST1
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST1
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST1
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST1
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST1
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST1
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST2
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST1
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST1
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST2
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST2
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST2
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST2
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST2
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST2
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST2
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST2
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST2
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST2
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST2
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST2
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST2
INFO:root:This is logging for TEST2
```

If it doesn't for you then you should [file a bug report with multiprocessing-logging](https://github.com/jruere/multiprocessing-logging/issues/new).

Comment: `IINFO:root:This is logging for TEST2
NFO:root:This is logging for TEST1`
Don't work for me